# Horinzontal Rule issues and help

Tags: rules

I am almost done with my resume but the only issue is providing horizontal line to add spacing and a sense of cleanliness in the article.

Here is the style that I am looking for-

[image]

But if I use `\hrulefill` it won't just start from the bottom of the heading and needs a line break for it to give the effect.

Secondly - is there a way to reduce the spacing between 2 `\items` bullets?

[image]

Here is the code for it !  I am not able to use `\hline` since I am not very familiar with it. `\rule` works almost similar to `\hrule` so same issues with it! Other than this I wanted the rule to be a bit larger than the heading as in first image~

Please not that `\headtitle` is a custom command that I using for simplifying my work~

```
{\bfseries{FREELANCER CONTRIBUTION}}

\hrulefill

\headtitle{Freelancer Author}{Linux / Online Magazines}{2009-2013}
\begin {itemize}
\item Published more than 30 artciles across various print and online magazines.
\item Worked on popular publications like Linux Journal , Linux Pro Magazine, Linux For     You \par(now Open Source for You) and Muktware.
\item Covered major critique  on Secure Boot , GPT, Gnome Extensions, Overclocking etc.
\end{itemize}
```

Kindly  help :)

Regards

Comment: Can you add a complete MWE showing your documentclass?

Comment: I am using `article` style for the document class ~ Not sure what you meant by MWE !?

Comment: MWE means [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is the usage of the environment `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcommand\myhead[4]{%
  \par\noindent%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries\RaggedRight}X>{\bfseries\Centering}X>{\bfseries\RaggedLeft}X@{}}
      \multicolumn{3}{@{}l@{}}{\bfseries #1}\tabularnewline\midrule
       #2 & #3 & #4 \tabularnewline
   \end{tabularx}\par%
}

\newcommand\myheadtitle[1]{%
\par\noindent\textbf{#1}\par\nointerlineskip\noindent\rule[-.2em]{\linewidth}{.4pt}\par%
}
\newcommand\headtitle[3]{\par\noindent\bfseries #1 \hfill #2 \hfill #3\par\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\myheadtitle{FREELANCER CONTRIBUTION}


\headtitle{Freelancer Author}{Linux / Online Magazines}{2009-2013}


\myhead{FREELANCER CONTRIBUTION}{Freelancer Author}{Linux / Online Magazines}{2009-2013}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: The problem is I want to keep the header and `\hline` in a separate section and dont want to include them in a single command as you did :/

Comment: @Shashwat: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative.

1. The rule command is `\rule[location]{width}{thickness}`
2. To adjust the space between 2 items space.  `\setlength\itemsep{-xx dimension}`
3. `\headtitle` is disable since OP did not provide it.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
{\bfseries{FREELANCER CONTRIBUTION}}

%\hrulefill

\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{0.1cm}
%\headtitle                 % This is removed since it is customized command
{Freelancer Author}{Linux / Online Magazines}{2009-2013}
\begin {itemize}
\setlength\itemsep{-0.4\baselineskip}
\item Published more than 30 artciles across various print and online magazines.
\item Worked on popular publications like Linux Journal , Linux Pro Magazine, Linux For You \par(now Open Source for You) and Muktware.
\item Covered major critique  on Secure Boot , GPT, Gnome Extensions, Overclocking etc.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example for the `\rule` yields the same result as of `\hrulefill` - There is a considerable amount of space between main heading and the rule! Thanks for the item spacing tip :)

Comment: @Shashwat -- You can move the rule up by changing [0pt] to [-5pt] ,for example, to reduce the space. Here [0pt] means the line is drawn on baseline. i.e, default position.